# How to load Apple Map and Google Map base on OS version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Because I have to work for map in the iOS 6 and older version. I'm looking for the source code example that can load both Google map and Apple map into map view depend on OS version. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `MKMapView` to your views and it will handle it automatically. On iOS < 6, it will load and display the old google maps, on iOS >= 6 it will display the new Apple maps. The API itself is the same for both versions, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about that. The maps API is almost identical. Apple made sure it was compatible with older versions. The only big difference is where the data is fetched from. If you run your application in iOS 6+ it will use apple maps, if you run it 5.1 and below then you will get google maps.